# GMSPanoramaService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate no result

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-street-view

Trying to request Google Panorama for a coordinate along with a specified radius.
Is there any way to get maximum supported radius for a coordinate ?
Just not sure what radius I can put into requestPanoramaNearCoordinate,
because even if I put 10000 (meters) it does not return any panorama (blank grey screen) where there are in fact panoramas within 50meters.

The requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:

```
[panoSvc requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:self.coordinate radius:1000 callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"StreetView is not available at latlong = %f,%f", self.coordinate.latitude, self.coordinate.longitude);
        return;
    }
    else{
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:self.coordinate];
        marker.panoramaView = panoView_;
        [panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:self.coordinate];
    }
}];
```

Comment: What lat and lon you use? Alternatively, you can use `- (void) requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)  coordinate callback:(GMSPanoramaCallback)callback` which does not require a radius parameter.

Comment: @ztan i  purposely want a street viewer image that is a bit far away from the destination, say about 100m away. but the requestPanoramaNearCoordinate doesn't quite work for me for that purpose, or I somehow misunderstood how to use it.

Comment: If you want to find a street view image 100m away from your destination, then you need to calculate the lat/lon which are 100m from your destination lat/lon. The method you use just means find the panoramaView which are 100m WITHIN your coordinate, NOT 100m away from your coordinate.

Comment: @ztan yes I do want to find panoramaView which are WITHIN 100m of my coordinate. I am sure the latlon I supplied is within 100m, but no hit. setting it to 1000m also gives no hit. If I move move coordinate 20m closer, suddenly there is a panorama. I wonder if this is a bug in GMS SDK

Comment: So what coordinate you use?

Comment: @ztan this coordinate (long 115.880583, lat -31.996522) has panoramas returned, but this one (long 115.880733, lat -31.996723) does NOT have any panoramas, and the radius is set to 1000
notice the two coordinate is only about 50meters away from each other

Comment: @ztan thanks for your curious questions which helped me find a flaw in my logic, if you are interested, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the panoramaView should be moved to panorama.coordinate, not to where the destination coordinate is (which is self.coordinate and where the marker is),
see the code following the comment below.

```
[panoSvc requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:self.coordinate radius:1000 callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"StreetView is not available at latlong = %f,%f", self.coordinate.latitude, self.coordinate.longitude);
    return;
}
else{
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:self.coordinate];
    marker.panoramaView = panoView_;
    //------------------
    //so I should move panoramaView to panorama coordinate, not to where the destination coordinate is (which is self.coordinate and where the marker is)
    //------------------
    [panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:panorama.coordinate];
}
```

}];